# Check total value

Tags: c#

I made a little script that checks if total value is above 10000. If it is; it returns true and gives a warning, if not; it returns false. 
Somehow my script always returns true. Does someone know why?

```
public Boolean Execute()
    {
        ScriptRecordset offerItemRS = this.GetRecordset("R_OFFERDETAILITEM", "" , "FK_OFFER = "+this.RecordId, "");
        if(offerItemRS != null && offerItemRS.RecordCount > 0)
        {
            offerItemRS.MoveFirst();
            double total = 0.00;

            while(!offerItemRS.EOF)
            {
                double price = (double)offerItemRS.GetField("TOTALAMOUNT").Value;
                total += price;
                offerItemRS.MoveNext();
            }

            if(total > 10000)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: check the value of total.

Comment: It means `total > 10000`. Debug the program

Comment: I can't use my debugger in Visual Studio ..

Comment: This seems to be a job for the database. There is no client side logic involved, so you should not transfer all the records to the client (C# Program) count them there and use the result. "SELECT SUM(TOTALAMOUNT) FROM R_OFFERDETAILITEM WHERE FK_OFFER = ?" should probably do the job easier and faster.

Comment: @Marijke you should work on using the debugger first. You will not be a happy or productive developer without it.

Comment: Initialize total and use a variable for the return code, initialize that variable properly as well.

Comment: Problem is that I need to use this little piece of code into a crappy designer, normally I do everything in Visual Studio. Also, I can't use linq or other direct query's. Really frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step through your code and watch the value `Total` is at when the while loop has read to the end of the file.

The likelihood is that your never reaching 10000 records.

But as the guy's have mentioned, using the debugger is a key component in being a software developer. If you chose to neglect to use this feature your not going to get very far.